# Append multiple DataFrame to multiple existing excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter-notebook, openpyxl

I have a relationship with multiple deliveries and multiple addresses.

I made a list of pivot tables for each region (5 regions)

Using "for" in jupyter notebook, each item in each list appears as a separate pivot table, one on top of the other, just the way I need it.

But how do I save them in an excel with 5 sheets?

I've tried everything and just save the last pivot created using each region's list, or save over the existing one and delete everything.

I currently created an empty spreadsheet for each region, with just a title in Column D, row 1.

expedition.xlsx (with 5 sheets inside, north, northeast, center west, southeast and south)

When I try to save, it ends up deleting the others and keeping only the 'north'

I put a rule to identify if column D has an empty cell, if it is filled, try again by skipping a line down, if it is empty, theoretically it should fill with the dataframe of the list.

[in this image it is like jupyter notebook display, as I would like it to be saved in excel (one pivot below the other, with 2 spaces)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIniP.png)

[Using openpyxl I managed to make the rule work and fill the first column below the spacing with an example 'aaaaaa' without needing to delete the other sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbagO.png)

How can I populate one Pivot Table below the other? For each region and list item.

code: https://pastebin.com/Cx3Zvf6D

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
 
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("expedition.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
 
# Creating the base sheet for each region, empty
pivot1 = pd.DataFrame({'Lista de Romaneio para Região Norte':  [' ']})
pivot2 = pd.DataFrame({'Lista de Romaneio para Região Nordeste':  [' ']})
pivot3 = pd.DataFrame({'Lista de Romaneio para Região Centro Oeste':  ['']})
pivot4 = pd.DataFrame({'Lista de Romaneio para Região Sudeste':  [' ']})
pivot5 = pd.DataFrame({'Lista de Romaneio para Região Sul':  [' ']})
 
# creating a sheet in the spreadsheet for each region, with the title in column D, row 1
pivot1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Norte', index=False, startcol=3, freeze_panes=(1,0))
pivot2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Nordeste', index=False, startcol=3, freeze_panes=(1,0))
pivot3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Centro Oeste', index=False, startcol=3, freeze_panes=(1,0))
pivot4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sudeste', index=False, startcol=3, freeze_panes=(1,0))
pivot5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sul', index=False, startcol=3, freeze_panes=(1,0))
 
writer.close()
 
# List with the "keys" of each pivot table for each region
norte = ['PA_BEL', 'TO_PMW', 'AC_RBR']
nordeste = ['AL_MCZ', 'PB_JPA', 'BA_SSA', 'RN_NAT', 'PE_REC', 'CE_FOR', 'MA_IMP', 'MA_THE', 'PI_THE', 'BA_FEC']
centro_oeste = ['GO_GYN', 'DF_BSB', 'GO_BSB', 'MT_CGB', 'MS_CGR']
sudeste = ['ES_SRR', 'MG_BHZ', 'SP_PNM', 'SP_JDI', 'RJ_RIO', 'MG_UDI']
sul = ['RS_POA', 'PR_CWB', 'SC_CCM', 'RS_RIA', 'SC_FLN']
 
 
# example for the north (norte) region
if len(norte) > 0:
    frete_expresso_norte = 0
    for filial in norte:
        # creating a pivot table for each flilial(key)
        pivot1 = df[df.Filial_Transportador == filial].pivot_table(
                         index=['BU', 'Sold to Region', 'Filial_Transportador', 'Sold_to_Name', 'Sold to City', 'Delivery'],
                         values=['Quantidade','Volume', 'Palete', 'Net Value'], aggfunc='sum',
                         margins=True)
        # reorders columns and renames ALL of pivot table to Total
        ordem_das_colunas = ['Quantidade', 'Volume', 'Palete', 'Net Value']
        pivot1 = pivot1[ordem_das_colunas].rename(index=dict(All='Total Romaneio'))    
        # creating subtotals and finding express shipping (if any)
        total_palete_norte = pivot1.groupby('Filial_Transportador')['Palete'].sum()[1]
        total_net_value_norte = pivot1.groupby('Filial_Transportador')['Net Value'].sum()[1]
        # save the pivot table (pivot1) in excel in the north sheet where it is blank
        # Here's where I want to put the code below saving the pivot table before starting the creation of the next one.
        # code under construction
        # after saving it continues normally
        if total_palete_norte >= 29 or total_net_value_norte >= 2500000:
            frete_expresso_norte = frete_expresso_norte + 1
        else:
            pass
        display(pivot1)
        
else:
    expedicao_norte = 'Não há volume para ser expedido à região Norte'
 
 
# Code under construction to insert inside the loop:
import openpyxl
 
# opening the spreadsheet with specific name
n = 0 # 0 = Norte / 1 = Nordeste / 2 = Centro Oeste / 3 = Sudeste / 4 = Sul
planilha_cx = openpyxl.load_workbook("Expedition.xlsx")
folhas = planilha_cx.sheetnames
folha = planilha_cx[folhas[n]]
 
# reading the cell
coluna = 4  # column D of the selected sheet
linha = 1  # start on the first line of the sheet
celula = folha.cell(linha, coluna).value
 
while celula != None:  # looping while cell in column D is not blank
    celula = folha.cell(linha, coluna).value  # cell current value
    
    if celula == None:  # filling the cell if it is blank
        linha = linha + 2
        folha.cell(row=linha, column=1).value = 'aaaaaaa'  # inserts the word 'aaaaa' but doesn't work with pivot1
        planilha_cx.save("Expedition.xlsx")
        break
                
    else:  # while cell D1 is not blank, add +1 to row
        linha = linha + 1
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, when loading to a workbook, you are creating a new object with a new sheet name for every load (you are somewhat solving this).
The trick is to let python/pandas know, that you are uploading to the same book with different sheets.

Try using this code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook(your_destination_file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(your_destination_file, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)  # tells 
pandas/python what the sheet names are

Your_dataframe.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=DesiredSheetname, startcol=3, 
freeze_panes=(1,0))

writer.save()
```

Above code should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this  should solve at least one problem. Do you know how  to save  a pivot into a existing excel file?

Comment: Pandas has an inbuilt pivot function you could use.
Is it important for you that it is live? You could consider saving your pandas outputs as csv files, then load them into excel with the "get data" function as tables. 

That way you aren't writing the frames to excel, but rather importing them and all your pictures/pivots etc. will still be there.

Comment: Interesting, so i can create a lot of csv files for each pivot, them get they data into the main excel file and delete them after (it will run 1 time per day).
But first i wan't to try this inbuilt pivot function, how it works? I i'm creating the pivots with pivot_table function but i can't copy

Comment: I think you would be better of with the latter. This way, you could dump your 5 csv files the same place each day, letting them overwrite the old ones, and simply click "refresh all" in excel letting you update all 5 pivot tables.